# How to backup OS-specific files with rsync? (Mac OS X to Ubuntu Server)

Tags: ubuntu, backup, mac-osx, rsync

I want to setup an automatic backup system using rsync to backup documents/source code from Mac OS X to Ubuntu Server.

I have some documents written in Pages (iWork), and lastly when I tried to backup these to the server, they looked like archive-files since Ubuntu OS don't recognize the Mac OS X specific file format *.pages. 
When I then took one of these files from the server and tried to open it in Pages on the Macbook, it couldn't open it!

This just can't happen, so how (if possible) can I get rid of this issue and ensure that even operating system specific files can be opened after the backup?

Kind regards,
Ramon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.pages` documents indeed *are* directories, not single files, just like many other MacOS things (Applications, `pkg` files etc.). This is called  a package in MacOS, and there is a special file system flag that tells the Finder to treat a certain directory as a package (you can look into it by `cd`ing into it in the shell or  right click the file in the Finder and select "Show Package Contents").

To keep the attributes, you'll have to use a newer `rsync` version then supplied by Apple, e.g. by installing it via Homebrew, and then use the `-X` option during the `rsync` operations.

Alternatively, `tar` the files on the MacOS side before copying to the backup server.

Comment: Actually when you're saying it, what is the preferred way to setup rsync with cronjob here? Since my Macbook will be the client and my Ubuntu Server the server? Should I setup the cronjob on the client or the server?

Answer (score 0):

My 'rsync client' app does exactly this.
It's a simple GUI for managing your remote files,
with the powerful rsync engine to haul data at high speed.
It looks like an FTP client but goes like rsync.
http://bonhardcomputing.com/rsync-client/

It carries the most modern version of rsync internally,
so it will deal with all those worries for you.
Please excuse the self promotion...